# How to get path by MediaStore.Images.Media

Tags: android

I use below code to get the bitmap of all sd card photo.

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};  
Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID); 
int count = cursor.getCount();
int image_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
path = new String[count];
bm = new Bitmap[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
cursor.moveToPosition(i);
int id = cursor.getInt(image_column_index);
path[i] //How to get path
bt[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
}
```

I already get the thumbnail of all photo.
But I want to get the absolute path.
Where should I modify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Images.ImageColumns.DATA` is the path

How to use it:

```
int image_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
int image_path_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
//added ... 
path[i] = cursor.getString(image_path_index);
```

Comment: May more detail about how to use it?

Comment: int image_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
int image_path_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); //added

...

path[i]  = cursor.getString(image_path_index); //added

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == yourRequestCode) {
                    currImageURI = data.getData();
            }
    }
}

// Convert the image URI to the direct file system path
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,
                    proj, // Which columns to return
                    null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                    null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                    null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

In Latest OS `managed query` is deprecated So use

`yourActivity.getContentResolver().query` instead of it, Both uses the same arguments