# delete image from gallery with OnItemLongClick event

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-image, android-file

I want to know how can I use OnItemLongClickListener event to delete an image from gallery?

I don't know how can I find the url or another detail about the image from this event 
in order to  delete it.

this is What I did so far (* I already have a gallery with images inside) :
First I connect the gallery to the event :

```
gallery.setOnItemLongClickListener(OnLongClickGallery);
```

Then I want to ask the user if he sure that he want to delete the image and in the same time save the data from the selected item:

```
private OnItemLongClickListener OnLongClickGallery = new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        //How I get the desired data here?
        showPopupMenu(arg1);// Show pop up list 
        return false;
    }
};
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you successful in fetching images from Gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take help from

- How to get a image and implementing click listener

http://androidsamples.blogspot.in/2009/06/how-to-display-thumbnails-of-images.html

- How to delete a image from content provider

[Deleting a gallery image after camera intent photo taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken)

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                     cr.delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                        BaseColumns._ID + "=" + c.getString(3), null);
```

EDIT:
To get path from content provider

```
image_path_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
path[i] = cursor.getString(image_path_index);
```

Comment: But I need the path or the file name.
How I get this?

Comment: one of the column in content provider is path

Images.ImageColumns.DATA is the path

[source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737054/how-to-get-path-by-mediastore-images-media)

Comment: check the edited comment and check the link mentioned in above comment about how to create a cursor